# How to "curve" microphone inputs for volume display

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am putting together a display for microphone input.  The devices the code runs on are Android, and the microphones behave very differently (some put out louder or quieter readings for the same source of audio).

All mics put out audio in the range:

```
-32767 to + 32767  (short in java).
```

I've currently applied a fast sigmoid function to the audio, to get it to fall within 0-1.

```
float value = sample /(1+(Math.abs(sample)));
```

I then scale this to fall between 0 and 100 for display purposes (the scale the drawing code uses).

I'd like to find a way to bend this so everything tends towards a middling value.  On some devices the readings are so quiet that i get values in the range of `0-20` almost exclusively, even when yelling.  On others normal speech blows the mic up completely (i.e. final readings of 100 all the way through).

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you scale `value = sample /(1+(Math.abs(sample)))`. Can you give an example of `sample` that results in a final reading of 0, and a `sample` for which the final reading is 20? What about the smallest positive value of `sample` that gives a final reading of 100?

Comment: oh sorry, i glossed over the scaling.  value = sample /(1+(Math.abs(sample))) gives a value between 0 and 1 (at least as far as I understand this).  I then multiply by 100 to scale it up.  I actually never see a value of 0 or 100 since the sigmoid doesn't actually reach 0 or 1 as far as I understand it.  the 0-20 example is just to say that on some devices, the range that sample takes is such that i only ever got very low numbers (between 0 and 20) which makes the mic input display look weird.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a logarithm base $2$:

$$ \frac{25}{4}\log_2(\text{sample} + 32768)$$

If "sample" is between $-32767$ and $32767$, then the thing above should be between $0$ and $100$. Since the decibel system is logarithmic, this may be desirable, but it depends on what the units of your input are.

---

If instead you'd like it to be linear, you could use

$$ \frac{\text{sample} + 32768}{655.36}$$

This would again give you a value strictly between $0$ and $100$.

---

EDIT: If negative samples represent sounds that are as loud as their positive counterparts, then you can replace the above two methods with these:

$$\frac{10}{3}\log_2 \left(\left|\text{sample}\right|+1\right)$$

And, if you prefer the linear version:

$$\frac{\left|\text{sample}\right|}{327.67}$$

Comment: Isn't $\log_2(x)$ undefined when $x \leq 0$? Maybe this would work: $$50 + \frac{10}{3}\log_2(\lvert x \rvert + 1) \cdot \text{sign}(x)$$

Comment: You're right. I think I fixed it.

Comment: I tried the first example and it seems to be producing some good results so far.  Let me get back to you once i've tested it more fully.

Comment: Hmm... There is one problem. Try plotting $$\log_2(\sin(x) + 1)$$ and you can see that $f(-x) \not = -f(x)$ which might be good condition.

Comment: No, I don't get what you mean ... ?

Comment: sample + 32768 is always at least 1

Comment: You did fix that part. I was thinking that typically sample values near zero are quite quiet and sample values with large absolute values are loud. So it might be good that mapped values follow same rule.

Comment: So is -30000 a really loud noise?

Comment: Yes. Also 30000 and -30000 sound practically same. (Assuming sample mean is zero)

Comment: @Reactant I added two changed formulas. How do they look?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee They are ok. I tested some of them. (plots have different scales). http://i.imgur.com/zO1mVL1.png